Connecting to supermicro IPMI
I got my hands on one of these and I have 2x Intel Xeon 2699 V4s. To have these CPUs recognized by a motherboard I would need to update the BIOS (I think).
One of the ways I found out to do this is via IPMI, however, since I bought this motherboard second hand it didn't come with default settings. So finding the IP of the IPMI was challenging (I used wireshark), but I think it's this:

I have my laptop connected to this board and I switched my IP to be in this subnet range, when I ping this address 10.129.238.238 I get Request timeout for icmp_seq 0. I can verify that the BMC light is flashing and the IPMI port is flashing yellow/orange:

Indicating some kind of activity, which I can see in the Wireshark too. Any idea what am I doing wrong? because the web interface is not loading. Also I tried ipmitool :
ipmitool -H 10.129.238.238 -I open user list
Password:
Error loading interface open

same outcome as the last one. Should I just put the CPUs in the sockets, put the memory, and have it boot to BIOS (or at least I'm hoping it's gonna boot to BIOS) and maybe reset IPMI that way? Any other hints?
Update
For everyone that might be in this situation. This is what I did:

Bought a CPU that was compatible with my board without bios update (good suggestion Nikita in the comments)
Got VGA cable to connect to the display and updated BIOS using UEFI shell and USB. I made a mistake and got a VGA to HDMI cable that cost me day of stress for no reason, just regular VGA cable worked fine (analog vs digital).
After doing BIOS update, then I mounted the 2 newer CPUs which were now being recognized by the motherboard.
Updated IPMI firmware using freedos bootable drive and IPMI update files that were copied onto the same USB stick.
As luck has it, I was using keyboard with a USB dongle, so during the IPMI update process the files from the USB were being copied/reference from the USB that was actually the dongle. Should have just used a keyboard. Anywho, had to do some scripting to fix the reference, nothing big.

Verdict, the IPMI was severly out of date as I wasn't able to use it even after I did BIOS update. Only after update it was useful and it's pretty dope now.

How do you know what is "this range"? Guess? So what IP did you use for the laptop? Also, before you use IP you had to make sure your laptop has got a correct ARP entry for the BMC; is it? It should, because BMC supposedly sent a gratuitous ARP, that's essentially unsolicited ARP reply. Check ip neigh show (or whatever is it in your laptop OS). // I'd suggest temporarily installing a CPU that this board already can recognize and boot with, then reset the BMC network setting from the OS with ipmitool using ipmi device interface and update BIOS. And then replace CPUs.
